# mutt: trash folder

Tags: mutt

I am trying to set up `trash` in mutt. The macro at [MacroSamples](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MacroSamples) does not work:

```
set maildir_trash=yes
set wait_key=no
folder-hook . 'bind index q quit'
folder-hook inbox 'macro index q ":unset maildir_trash;push \"T~D\\n<tag-prefix-cond>m=trash\\n<end-cond><quit>\"\n"'
```

when I press `d` nothing happens. When I pres `q` instead of exiting, mutt asks:

```
Subject: <end-cond><quit>
```

I have to cancel it with <kbd>CTRL-c</kbd>

Can somebody please advise how to set up `trash folder` that actually works?

Comment: Have you tried this patch: http://cedricduval.free.fr/mutt/patches/#trash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/f508fa1d0d73791973d1583b7f349cee93fd60e8/.muttrc#L24-L27) has worked for me for some time:

```
unset confirmappend
folder-hook . set trash="=trash"
folder-hook trash$ unset trash
```

That is, move emails to the `trash` folder when deleting, unless you are in the `trash` folder.

Comment: works nice, thank you. Would you know how to make it work without the delete confirmation? I.e., I want to press `d`, then `$` and that's it.

Comment: You might want to make that a separate question :)

Comment: I have created a new question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105759/mutt-trash-macro

Answer (score 6):

According to the `mutt` documentation, setting the trash variable does this.

[Mutt documentation RE trash](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#trash)

I set this in my `.muttrc`:

```
set trash=+"Trash"
```

and it appears to work. (I'm on an IMAP server.) It does query if you want to copy the mail to the Trash folder, just like saving in another folder. And, if you are in the Trash directory and you delete a message, it asks if you want to save it to Trash. But I don't generally go into the Trash directory and delete items. I let the server do it after the specified time period.