# mutt: trash macro

Tags: mutt

In my previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104272/mutt-trash-folder) I have learned how to implement `trash` functionality in `mutt`.

```
unset confirmappend
folder-hook . set trash="=trash"
folder-hook trash$ unset trash
```

That works well, except that I have to confirm every deletion. I would like it to work without the delete confirmation. So that I only need to press <kbd>d</kbd> and then <kbd>$</kbd> to sync, without being asked for confirmation.

Can somebody please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set delete=yes
```

That didn't work for me.

I have a different trash setting, so maybe it won't work for you. I did:

```
set confirmappend=no
folder-hook . 'macro index d "<save-message>=INBOX.Trash<enter>"'
folder-hook =trash 'macro index d <delete-message>'
```

I guess you should remove from your configuration:

```
unset confirmappend
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this in  [.muttrc](https://github.com/bnadland/config/blob/master/.muttrc)

```
# delete without confirmation
set delete=yes
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to OP's question and the only thing needed. The accepted answer is a confusing mash from a different setup.